# Не могу привести кириллицу к верхнему регистру

Tags: c++

Пытался привести кириллицу к верхнему регистру используя wchar_t. Для этого был написан следующий код:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    wchar_t strr[] = L"Привет";
    for(int i = 0; strr[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        strr[i] = towupper(strr[i]);
        
    wcout << strr << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

На выходе получаю следующее: Privet

Хотя ожидается, что слово будет приведено к верхнему регистру. Работаю из Ubuntu 20.04 и сперва думал, что проблема из-за отсутствия русской локали, однако после установки таковой ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Насколько я знаю локаль называется `ru_RU.utf8`, а не `rus`.

Comment: Именно такая локаль и установлена

Comment: Значение, возвращаемое setlocale, необходимо проверять, чтобы убедится, что функция выполнена успешно. Нельзя подсовывать этой функции произвольные названия локалей и надеяться, что оно сработает. Ну и для такого рода манипуляций используйте ICU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я сделал буквально одно маленькое изменение и все работает

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "uk_UA.utf8");
    wchar_t strr[] = L"Привет";
    for(int i = 0; strr[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        strr[i] = std::towupper(strr[i]);

    std::wcout << strr << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

с указанием `std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.utf8");` у меня не работает нормально. Потом вернул `setlocale(LC_ALL,"uk_UA.utf8");` (заметьте, что setlocale и std::setlocale - это могут быть две разные функции!!!) и все равно все работает. А с "rus" - никак.

Но потом я посмотрел в вывод `locale -a` и понял, что нет у меня этой локали. Поэтому, добавляем локаль, проверяем, что она есть, а потом, код заработает.

Добавляем локали

```
sudo locale-gen ru_RU
sudo locale-gen ru_RU.UTF-8
sudo update-locale
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь! Теперь всё работает

Comment: Советую устанавливать локаль по умолчанию, а не какую-то конкретную: `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");`

Comment: ага. я попробовал. Оно выбрало как дефолтную en_US.utf8 и ничего не преобразует...

Comment: @KoVadim, не верю... во всех utf-8 локалях это должно работать корректно... подразумевая, конечно, что они установлены и настроены... по крайней мере в glibc...

Comment: вроде заработало, но нужно ещё разок проверить (у меня особо настроенная система:) )